# Plotting Excel data using a function that specifies which column to use for the colourbar

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, colorbar

Sorry I'm very new to coding and hope this is ok to ask.

I have an excel spreadsheet that has multiple sheets, and they have columns X, Y, Z1 and Z2, for example:

```
X   Y   Z1  Z2
726841.75   7836563.42  21.78   4.26
726709.69   7836391.55  29.81   14.99
726633.57   7836014.98  33.61   19.18
726596.34   7835726.40  55.67   38.04
726562.61   7835415.88  63.88   21.60
726529.13   7835185.27  58.39   28.52
726494.13   7834882.61  61.48   22.97
```

I would like to go through the sheets and plot X and Y (as coordinates) and have either Z1 or Z2 as the colour attribute by specifying which one in a function.

So far I can plot X and Y and have Z1 as the colorbar:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot(workbook, names):
    for sheet in names:
        df = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name=(sheet))
        plt.scatter(df["X"], df["Y"], c=df["Z1"],cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=650)

workbook = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
names = workbook.sheet_names
```

But I want to interchange Z1 with Z2 as part of the function so it could be plot(workbook, names, Z) where Z can be either the Z1 or Z2 column. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO. No need to apologize for asking. But you should clarify your question a little, because in general the scatter command you posted should work. But we cannot know how your data looks like. Please post for the beginning the result of `df.head()`. Also you do not really describe _what_ is the unexpected behaviour, so please tell what you want to achieve and what exactly goes wrong. And please note that your code was not displayed correctly, I'll fix it as such as I think you meant it, so please check.

Comment: Thank you. And now in which function do you want to add what additional argument to achieve what and what else does then happen?

Comment: Thanks @SpghttCd! I've tried to make it clearer. Instead of Z1, I'd like to plot the colourbar using the Z2 column, and I'd like that as an argument in the function. For example plot(workbook, names, Z), but if I enter df["Z2"] in there it says NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Comment: Perfect, thats exactly how you could do that. Z should be then a string, actually in this case either `'Z1'` or `'Z2'` afaik and in your scatter command you only have to exchange the constant string `"Z1"` against the variable `Z`.

Comment: Now I see you entered `df["Z2"]` into the call of the function, like `plot('test.xlsx', names, df["Z2"])`. But df is created _within_ the function definition, so it's not known outside. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an example:

```
def plot(workbook, names, c_col):
    for sheet in names:
        df = pd.read_excel(workbook, sheet_name=(sheet))
        plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c=df[c_col], cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=650)
plot('test.xlsx', names, 'Z2')
```

Note that pandas builds on top of matplotlib, so if your data is in a pandas dataframe, you have access to some convenient plotting functions from matplotlib.
You might want to try e.g.:

```
df.plot.scatter('X', 'Y', c=c_col, cmap='viridis', vmin=0, vmax=650)
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, that makes sense. Thank you for the help!